Strange Ethernet issue - Ubuntu 24.04.1
out of nowhere i'm having this extremely annoying and strange behavior.
Basically when I boot the pc, almost always the wired connection has a question mark on the ethernet icon.
While the connection is in this state, i can't access the internet.
The only solution that I found is to manually turn off and on the wired connection (either from top bar or settings).
I really can't think a reason for this strange behaviour, so I looked online and tried a couple of things:

Editing (or in my case creating) sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
and added :

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
This actually made things worse since at some point the wired connection was completely removed and I couldn't connect via ethernet anymore (until I removed this file).

Then I tried to set the auto-connect manually (for ethernet and
loopaback):

sudo nmcli connection lo reload
nmcli connection modify enp4s0 connection.autoconnect yes # the ethernet
nmcli connection modify lo connection.autoconnect yes  # the loopback

I also tried to re-install Realtek drivers:

sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
Didn't change anything.

I uninstalled the NordVPN client to remove any possibilities, nothing

Since I don't know what else to do, I'm asking for help. I would rather not having to do a fresh install, if possible.
I would also consider a valid option having a command that could do the "switch-off -- switch-on" to make it automatic in one of my scripts, which currently can't even start.
System & general info:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS x86_64

Kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic

Result for: lspci | grep -i eth
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)

Result for: lsmod | grep r8169


r8169 118784 0

The cable is CAT6 and works flawlessly

The settings in Advanced Network Configuration are default:
Connect automatically with priority is set to 0
All users can connect to the network
The Ethernet page too have default settings:
Device name - enp4s0
MTU automatic

Also by going through network settings I made sure "Connect
automatically" was checked

I tried to ping 1.1.1.1 after rebooting the system:


PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
46 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 45001ms
(I interrupted it after a while)
No problems after doing the switch thing
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=12.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=12.6 ms
